# Routing Doesn't Work After A Publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a .NET 4.0 "Web Application" aka "Web Forms".  Inside this application I have a "Web API Controller Class", and my "Global.asax"

Inside Global.asax I have the following code in my "Application_Start" method.

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi"
, routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"
, defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional });
```

When I start a local debugging session, I can use my routes just fine.  If I type in "/api/ZipCodes", I get my expected JSON response.

When I publish my project, to my remote IIS server (publish method: File System) the route no longer works.  I get a 404 error.

I am assuming there is a setting or something I need to enable on IIS in order for it to recognize and use routes.

- IIS version 7.0.6000.16386
- .NET Application Pool version 4.0
- My website resides in "C:\inetpub\hosts" along with 7+ other websites that all work.  None use routing.
- I have a Default.aspx with "Hello World", and I can access that correctly on the remote IIS server and on my local debug session.
- When I debug on my local machine, I can enter "http://localhost:6358/api/ZipCodes" and get my JSON response.  If I enter the same url on my remote machine "http://remoteserver.com/api/ZipCodes", it gives me a 404.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your home folder set correctly? Because that's what happened to me today.
It should point to the root folder of the application, not the root of the server.

EDIT: Could you give us the folder you published your application to?

Also, if you want to know how to setup the **"Home Folder"** (The folder the server points to when a request is made to i.e.: www.yoursite.com) take a look at this link:
https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a59a2665-9078-43ef-8b5a-5bf9bcacc95e.mspx?mfr=true

**TO SUM UP:**

You'll have to setup your **"Home Folder"** to point to the **application's folder**, or put your **application files** to the **preset folder** (think it's named something like this:  **LocalDrive:\Inetpub\Wwwroot**)

Comment: Que?  I'm not familiar with "Home Folder".  I just set up an IIS web application, point it to a folder on my servers C:/, and then publish over the network.

Comment: Try to enter your sitename as a "folder" i.e.: www.example.com/example

Answer (score 0):

If you have your IIS up to date (I am assuming 7.0 or later), with the application pool configured to user framework 4.0, should work with any other action or configuration.

Comment: IIS 7.0.6000.16386 , and application pool is set to v4.0

Comment: what kind of url are you using on the remote server? If you try to navigate something else on this site works?